# Shower cartridge is difficult to remove

Tags: plumbing, shower, cartridge

I'm trying to fix the shower in our guest bathroom, and as far as I can tell, the shower cartridge just needs to be replaced. I'm trying to access it, but having difficulty removing the brass housing that holds it in place.

Rather than a locking pin, this one has a huge nut on the front. Unfortunately it's really slim and my adjustable wrenches keep slipping off. Is this all one piece, where I can grab further back on the body, or does that run the risk of damaging something?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a thermostatic mixing valve. Do you have a brand and model #?

Comment: @HoneyDo The only thing I can find is "873-7004" on the back of the shower handle, which Google takes me to this being a Pegasus Estates Shower Handle. "LASCO 0-1071 Pegasus Brand, Single Lever Cartridge" on Amazon looks like it matches the cartridge, but I can't figure out how to get the cartridge out to check.

Comment: You may need a large/deep 6-point socket for this. The deliberately rounded off corners are distinctly non-user-friendly.

Comment: 873-7004 is the model # for the Pegasus single handle tub and shower valve. So at least you know the correct cartridge. I'm not familiar with removing that cartridge but you may be able to find a user manual online or check with the cartridge supplier (Lasco?) to see if installation instructions are included with the new cartridge.